Do parallel execution policies require the iterator reference types to be lvalues?
I traced down a performance problem in my code caused by the lack of parallelism for an algorithm invoked with a parallel execution policy on a non-lvalue range.
Consider the following code that illustrates the behavior:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <ranges>

#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>

struct Timer {
    Timer() : start{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()} {}
    ~Timer() {
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start) << '\n';
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start;
};

auto fn    = [](int) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
};

void run(std::ranges::range auto&& rng) {
    Timer timer;
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, rng.begin(), rng.end(), fn);
}

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 200;
    run(std::views::iota(0, N));                                                                // not parallel
    run(std::array<int, N>{});                                                                  // parallel
    run(std::array<int, N>{} | std::views::transform([](auto& elem) { return elem * 2; }));     // not parallel
    run(std::array<int, N>{} | std::views::transform([](auto& elem) -> int& { return elem; })); // parallel
    {
        Timer timer;
        tbb::parallel_for(0, N, fn);                                                            // parallel
    }
    return 0;
}

Assuming the parallel function only requires const access (which is very common), the 3rd case seems limiting.  Is this behavior required by the standard?

It does in C++17 and C++20, but since C++23 it doesn't. Technically speaking your calls are ill-formed before C++23, as you are violating library function preconditions.
Wording from C++17

If an algorithm's template parameter is named ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator1, or ForwardIterator2, the template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a forward iterator.


A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if

if X is a mutable iterator, reference is a reference to T; if X is a constant iterator, reference is a reference to const T


Wording from C++20

If an algorithm's template parameter is named ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator1, or ForwardIterator2, the template argument shall meet the Cpp17ForwardIterator requirements


A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if

if X is a mutable iterator, reference is a reference to T; if X is a constant iterator, reference is a reference to const T


Wording from C++23

If an algorithm's template parameter is named ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator1, ForwardIterator2, or NoThrowForwardIterator, the template argument shall meet the Cpp17ForwardIterator requirements if it is required to be a mutable iterator, or model forward_iterator  otherwise.


Using c++23 does not impact whether or not a particular call to run() is parallelized

@MarkB but it does make your calls well-formed. std::execution::par is only permission to parallelise, it isn't a requirement to.
